# How can I know which shell I am using?

Tags: linux, shell

I am writing a shell script. The tutorial that I am reading have the first line like this :

`#!/usr/bin/env bash/`

but it isn't working for me. (`error : no such directory`)

How can I find out which bash I am using and where is it located?

Appreciate for any advice and help.

**Thanks a lot. It works now**.

**solution is**  `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Another problem: Why it just can't read the word 'restart'

my code in the start.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash/
RESTART="apachectl restart"
$RESTART
```

I does not work.

```
Usage: /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd [-D name] [-d directory] [-f file]
                                [-C "directive"] [-c "directive"]
                                [-k start|restart|graceful|graceful-stop|sto                                                                             p]
                                [-v] [-V] [-h] [-l] [-L] [-t] [-S]
Options:
-D name            : define a name for use in <IfDefine name> directives
-d directory       : specify an alternate initial ServerRoot
-f file            : specify an alternate ServerConfigFile
-C "directive"     : process directive before reading config files
-c "directive"     : process directive after reading config files
-e level           : show startup errors of level (see LogLevel)
-E file            : log startup errors to file
-v                 : show version number
-V                 : show compile settings
-h                 : list available command line options (this page)
-l                 : list compiled in modules
-L                 : list available configuration directives
-t -D DUMP_VHOSTS  : show parsed settings (currently only vhost settings)
-S                 : a synonym for -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
-t -D DUMP_MODULES : show all loaded modules
-M                 : a synonym for -t -D DUMP_MODULES
-t                 : run syntax check for config files
```

why is it like that? it seems that it can read the word restart.

Thank you all! I have fixed it now.

**solution**: edit the file in unix (vim/nano and whatever but not in windows)

```
Thank again :)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ca try the following command

```
which bash
```

at a shell. Then put

```
#!<the output of which bash>
```

Comment: yep, I tryed. but when I ` ./start.sh/ ` the output is ` -bash: ./start.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory `

Comment: ^M .. tada ! you created that file in windows, right?  unix text file is incompatible with windows text file..   convert it with unix2dos or just create it in linux.

Answer (score 15):

Yet another way: `echo $SHELL`.

Answer (score 4):

If you remove the `/` from `bash/`, it should work.

Comment: output `: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

To find out where bash is, issue the command:

```
type bash
```

at your command prompt. and to make sure it is always found by your script use:

```
#!bash
```

this has the problem that some other bash may be found and used, which could be security issue, but I have been doing this for years.

Comment: I am not sure if I get you right. When I use that command it show `bash is /bin/bash` then do you mean that I should use `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @Newbie you certainly can use that.

Comment: I used this and when I run the script. It shows `-bash: ./start.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @Newbie somehow you have managed to get a carriage return in your script - what did you edit it with?

Comment: Butterworth thank you a lot. I know where it goes wrong now. and your are right it due to the way i edit it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra character(s) you have at the end of lines. No slash is required and 
`dos2unix yourscript` will remove the unwanted CRs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually better would be to open a new question for your restart problem.
Most probably you are not at the directory where the restart command is
defined or restart is not in your path. Try putting the whole path.